# When $A$ and $B$ are divided by $173$, the remainder is $33$ and $17$ respectively. Find the remainder when $2A+B$ is divided by $173.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Question: When positive integer $A$ is divided by $173$, the remainder is $33$, and when positive integer $B$ is divided by $173$, the remainder is $17$. What is the remainder when $2A+B$ is divided by $173$?

This is GRE quant question, and the solution says that it is valid to assume that both $A$ and $B$ have the same quotient. Then, $A = B + 16$.

$2(A)+B = 2(B+16)+B = 3B+32$.  Therefore, the remainder is $17\cdot 3 + 32 = 83$.

But, I don't understand the assumption above. How can we assume that $A$ and $B$ have the same quotient??

Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: it's 13 in the title instead of 173 I corrected it

Comment: `the solution says that it is valid to assume that both A and B have the same quotient` That's a terribly worded hint if that's indeed what it said. What it meant, instead, is that the quotients do not actually matter when finding the remainder of the sum. Just suppose that $A=173 a + 33$ and $B=173 b +17$, then $\,2A+B=173(2a+b) + 83\,$ regardless of what $\,a, b\,$ are, equal or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking

$$A= 173Q_1 + 33$$
$$B = 173Q_2 + 17$$

then

$$2A+B= 2(173Q_1+33) + 173Q_2+17=173(2Q_1+Q_2)+2(33)+17$$

The answer is $2(33)+17$.

Whether $Q_1=Q_2$ holds, doesn't influence the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct indeed we have that

- $A = 33+173k$
- $B = 17+173h$

then

- $2A+B=83+173(2k+h)$

Regarding the hint, it says that we can assume $h=k$ maybe to facilitate an evaluation by direct calculation but obviously it is not a necessary condition.